# Sharepoint form fields validation

Tags: forms, list, validation, sharepoint, field

I have a sharepoint list with below fields.

Name: (Input text Field) 
Area: (Choice Field) - Drop-down type
Pin code: (Input text Field)

All the above fields should not empty while saving the form.

I want to use multiple **IF** conditions in the PreSaveAction, if any conditions failed ,it should return false.

```
    If statement1 {
    conditions1
    return true; 
//if failed return false;
    }
    else if statement2 {
    conditions2
    return true;
//if failed return false;
    }
    else if statement3{
    conditions
    return true;
//if failed return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking for the technique how to validate fields in a SharePoint form? There are several options and I would consider using JSLink for that. Or are you struggling to write valid javascript code? Then take a look here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx

Comment: thanks, exactly what i want...

Comment: Good, please give me an upvote if I could help you :)

Comment: how to do that, show me please...i tried clicking the triangle button , but it showing me the notification as "you cannot vote your post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for the technique how to validate fields in a `SharePoint` form?

There are several options and I would consider to use `JSLink` for that.

Or are you struggling to write valid JavaScript code?
Then take a look [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx).